# Flask Error: Unable to load celery application

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, celery, celery-task

Please help me to get out of this problem I am getting this when I am running

```
celery -A app.celery worker --loglevel=info
```

Error:

```
Unable to load celery application.
The module app.celery was not found.
```

My code is--

```
#  Celery Configuration
from celery import Celery
from app import app
print("App Name=",app.import_name)

celery=Celery(app.name,broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)

@celery.task
def download_content():
    return "hello"
```

directory structure--
newYoutube/app/auth/routes.py and this function is present inside routes.py
auth is blueprint.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When invoking celery via

```
celery -A app.celery ...
```

celery will look for the name `celery` in the `app` namespace, expecting it to hold an instance of `Celery`. If you put that elsewhere (say, in `app.auth.routes`), then celery won't find it.

I have a working example you can crib from at https://github.com/davewsmith/flask-celery-starter

Or, refer to chapter 22 of the [Flask Mega Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world), which uses `rx` instead of `celery`, but the general approach to structuring the code is similar.

Answer (score 0):

Return both celery and app from your create_app function if you are using one e.g

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    # app config ...

    celery=Celery(app.name,broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)

    return app, celery
```